# How to show warranty expiration date in Sales Order View Page

Tags: magento-1.7, sales, order-status

I am looking for a way to hook into one of the Magento events that define Order creation Date. I would like to add a counter next to it that shows how many days/weeks/months ago the order was placed.

The reason is some items have extended warranties while others do not so if I could simply calculate the date then customer service could quickly establish whether the item is still covered by the warranty.

I am not sure how I should go about doing this. If anyone would like to lend a hand I would be very grateful for the help...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via **PHP Datetime addition** (based on the date of purchase) and set the information on the order at the time of purchase (calculate the date the warranty expires, and store to the order).

**Datetime addition, store to quote:**

```
$date = new DateTime($order->getCreatedAt());
$date->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
$quote->setWarrantyExpirationDate($date->format('Y-m-d'));
$quote->save();
```

If you'd rather calculate it on the fly - it's a very simple change:

```
$date = new DateTime($order->getCreatedAt());
$date->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Further reading:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php